# As in argparse use mutually exclusive arguments?

Tags: python, argparse, command-line-interface

A must-read list of some data (eg email addresses) from the command line:

```
some_util -l email1@x.com email2@x.com
```

or from a file:

```
some_util -L email.lst
```

How to make that not be able to use a combination of two key -l and -L in argparse

```
import argparse
import sys
def createCLParser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', nargs='+', help='list from comand line')
    parser.add_argument('-L', '--list-file', type=argparse.FileType(), help='list from file')
    return parser
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = createCLParser()
    namespace = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
```

In argparse is a method **add_mutually_exclusive_group ()** but it must be optional.

Comment: Why should these be mutually exclusive? What if I had a file and I wanted to *add* some email addresses on the command line?

Comment: Why not check the existence of both flags manually, after the fact? I feel like that's a better solution in general, as it makes your code easier to reconfigure down the line.

Comment: This is precisely what `add_mutually_exclusive_group()` is designed for. What about it doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`.add_mutually_exclusive_group()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_mutually_exclusive_group) method with `required=True`:

```
import argparse
import sys
def createCLParser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    group.add_argument('-l', '--list', nargs='+', help='list from comand line')
    group.add_argument('-L', '--list-file', type=argparse.FileType(), help='list from file')

    return parser
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = createCLParser()
    namespace = parser.parse_args(sys.argv[1:])
    print namespace
```

Usage:

```
$ python ar.py 
usage: ar.py [-h] (-l LIST [LIST ...] | -L LIST_FILE)
ar.py: error: one of the arguments -l/--list -L/--list-file is required

$ python ar.py -l foo@example.com
Namespace(list=['foo@example.com'], list_file=None)

$ python ar.py -l foo@example.com -L bar
usage: ar.py [-h] (-l LIST [LIST ...] | -L LIST_FILE)
ar.py: error: argument -L/--list-file: not allowed with argument -l/--list
```

Answer (score 0):

Because one of them is required, this use case is better suited for subcommands:

```
some_util fromList email1@x.com email2@x.com
```

or

```
some_util fromFile email.lst
```

The code would resemble

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
addr_parser = subparsers.add_parser("fromList")
file_parser = subparsers.add_parser("fromFile")

addr_parser.add_argument("addresses", nargs="+")
addr_parser.setdefaults(command="fromList")
file_parser.add_argument("address_file")
file_parser.setdefaults(command="fromFile")

parser.set_defaults(
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.command == "fromList":
    # use args.addresses
elif args.command == "fromFile":
    # read addresses from file named by args.address_file
```